# How to update a JSF Backing Bean, with data from an SVG element after each move?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsf, svg

I am new to using JSF, and I have an application that uses Prime Faces and SVG.

I have multiple SVG rect elements on the screen, each created from values that are passed from my bean up on the server. i.e., #{bean.x},....,.  Each element is clickable, and is able to be dragged.  When an element is done being dragged and you release the mouse, I would like to fire an event to get the SVG element's id, and update the corresponding  x and y in the bean.

i.e., drag svg element 52, from 100, 100 to 120, 100, after I release my mouse update array element 52's x and y in my bean to 120,100.

I have thought of a couple of ways to do this.

1. Since the values of my SVG elements are passed from my bean, is it possible to bind it so that when the svg element is moved it is automatically updated?  My buddy told me it is possible, and that to do this I would have to make a "Custom Component." I'm not sure how to go about that completely, does anyone have any idea if this is the right path or true?  If so any advice or help with this?
2. I was adding an onClick to each SVG Element that would fire an ajax call and pass the data to the bean, but I feel this defeats the purpose of JSF to use Javascript(but sometimes we need it, it seems...)?  IT seems this would work as well, but not sure if this is the best path either.

I'm not sure if there are other ways, or what is the correct way to go about this, but I'm not sure how to advance.

If there are any questions or comments, please let me know, thank you!

Comment: This question is way too broad. It boils down that you start with #2 and then once you get it all to work, then you "hide" it away in a nice custom JSF component like `<my:svg moveListener="#{bean.move}">` as described in #1.

Comment: I'm sorry :(.  I guess I will just do it this way, then thank you!